# Deriving nth Gray code from the (n-1)th Gray Code

Tags: bit-manipulation, gray-code

Is there a way to derive the 4-bit nth Gray code using the (n-1)th Gray code by using bit operations on the (n-1)th Gray Code?

For example the 4th Gray code is 0010. Now I want to get the 5th Gray Code, 0110, by doing bit operations on 0010.

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21823754/1364752) this answer that covers the problem (and a bit more) no matter the number of bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's "cheating" but you can just pack a lookup table into a 64-bit constant value, like this:

```
0000 0 -> 1
0001 1 -> 3
0011 3 -> 2
0010 2 -> 6
0110 6 -> 7
0111 7 -> 5
0101 5 -> 4
0100 4 -> C
1100 C -> D
1101 D -> F
1111 F -> E
1110 E -> A
1010 A -> B
1011 B -> 9
1001 9 -> 8
1000 8 -> 0

FEDCBA9876543210 nybble order (current Gray code)
|              |
V              V
EAFD9B80574C2631 next Gray code
```

Then you can use shifts and masks to perform a lookup (depending on your language):

```
int next_gray_code(int code)
{
     return (0xEAFD9B80574C2631ULL >> (code << 2)) & 15;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the formula for converting from [Gray to binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code), increment the value, and then convert from binary to Gray, which is just n xor (n / 2):

```
int next_gray_code(int code)
{
    code = code ^ (code >> 2);
    code = code ^ (code >> 1);
    code = (code + 1) & 15;
    return code ^ (code >> 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
t1 := XOR(g0, g1)
b0 := !XOR(g0, g1, g2, g3)
b1 := t1 & g2 & g3 + !t1 & !g2 & !g3
b2 := t1 & g2 & !g3
b3 := t1 & !g2 & !g3

n0 := XOR(b0, g0)
n1 := XOR(b1, g1)
n2 := XOR(b2, g2)
n3 := XOR(b3, g3)
```

The current gray code word is `g3 g2 g1 g0` and the next code word is `n3 n2 n1 n0`. `b3 b2 b1 b0` are the four bits which flip or not flip a bit in the code word to progress to the subsequent code word. Only one bit is changed between adjacent code words.