# Use of __builtin_expected for bounds check

Tags: c, branch-prediction, gray-code

I have this function which, given a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), returns the next Gray code. You can find a more complete explanation about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21823754/1364752). The thing is that I wanted to make this increment function modular so that incrementing the Gray code corresponding to `UINT_MAX` returns the Gray code corresponding to `0` (respectively the most significant bit and `0`). Since it is not the default behaviour, I added a check for this special case. Here is the complete algorithm:

```
unsigned next_gray(unsigned gray)
{
    static const unsigned msb
        = 1u << (CHAR_BITS - sizeof(unsigned) - 1u);

    // gray is odd
    if (__builtin_parity(gray))
    {
        if (__builtin_expect(gray == msb, false))
        {
            return 0u;
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned y = gray & -gray;
            return gray ^ (y << 1u);
        }
    }

    // gray is even
    return gray ^ 1;
}
```

So, the actual question is actually about branch prediction. I have often read that `__builtin_expect` is to be used only when a branch is really likely to be chosen or really unlikely to be chosen, the common example being for speeding a program up when there are no errors.

Considering that I am not handling an error case, I am unsure whether using `__builtin_expect` for bounds checking like this is a good idea at all. Is this a good place to use `__builtin_expect` or is incrementing the max value a common enough operation to deceive branch prediction?

**Note:** as always, comments and answers highlight things that are not clear in my questions :)

I will give a bit more context: this function is meant to be part of a library, developed for the sake of being a library and not used by any actual project as of know. Therefore, adding `__builtin_expect` implies that I expect people to mostly increment other values then the maximum value; without any actual project at hand, I wish to know whether this is a safe assumption.

Comment: There are some interesting discussions on the useful of this in: [Is there a compiler hint for GCC to force branch prediction to always go a certain way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30130930/1708801)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the GCC online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

You may use `__builtin_expect` to provide the compiler with branch prediction information. **In general, you should prefer to use actual profile feedback for this (`-fprofile-arcs`), as programmers are notoriously bad at predicting how their programs actually perform.** However, there are applications in which this data is hard to collect.

> Is this a good place to use __builtin_expect or is incrementing the max value a common enough operation to deceive branch prediction?

This all depends on your application.  If the value of `gray` is uniformly distributed then it will be 1 out of `(UINT_MAX+1)`, but can you say that for sure?  This is why the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) recommend using `-fprofile-arcs`.

The [gcov wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov) actually contains a nice simple example on how to use `-fprofile-arcs` and [`gcov`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) to get the information to make an informed decision.

Update:

If you can't profile, then all things being equal the edge case `gray == msb` is very unlikely so you are *probably* safe with your use of `__builtin_expect`.  However, if you can't profile because you don't know how your library is going to be used this sounds more like [pessimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312003/what-is-the-most-ridiculous-pessimization-youve-seen) than optimization.  If I use your library and always pass in `gray` such that it equals `msb` than your library won't be as fast for me.  General libraries that aren't written with a specific application in mind generally try to be good for the average case or without making any assumptions about input.  This is why you see different implementations of `malloc` such as [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) and [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html).  Both are optimized for very specific use cases and if you use it in a way that isn't like what it was optimized for it won't do as well.  Also [this blog article](http://blog.man7.org/2012/10/how-much-does-builtinexpect-like-and.html) might be of some interest to you.

Comment: I know about this advice, but I'm developing a library. And since I don't have a project to exploit it, running profiling data would be rather meaningless. My problem is that I think that projects using the library (none as of today) wouldn't call the special most of the time (like *most* of the time) but can't be sure.